# google cloud datastore + android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I'm new to android programming and here's what I want to do / my questions

I am starting with a simple app, letting users register and collect some info such as

username, password, age, etc

then later allow them to login and query for other users, ie, age <=30,

I google searched a bit and think google cloud datastore is what I want to go with, I want to pass data from the app to the database to establish a user database, which will be used later for queries.

My question is how do I do this, can someone point me to a link or tutorial? I read the google documents and they are not too helpful

Thanks